# CARTO VL time steps not working

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-vl

I am new to CARTO VL and i want to make a simple dashboard with an animation panel as shown in [one CARTO VL guide](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/guides/animated-visualizations/#taking-it-further).

The problem that i get is that when i try to animate it by the atribute of time of the GeoJSON, it doesn't work.

```
const viz = new carto.Viz(`
     @animation: animation(linear($TIME, time('2019-03-22T00:00:00'), time('2019-03-24T23:00:00')))
```

I don't know if it has to be with my GeoJSON time format.

Comment: Could you add an example of the GeoJSON used? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sure! var malla = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "MALLA",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "LEFT": 29.59,
        "BOTTOM": -1.3,
        "RIGHT": 29.6,
        "TOP": -1.29,
        "TOTAL": 1,
        "TIME": "2019-03-22T00:00:00",
        "ZSCORE": -2,
        "PVALOR": 0
      },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several issues here:

1. Your GeoJSON doesn't include the feature geometry. It should have the geometry type and the coordinates:

```js
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [ 30, 10 ]
}
```

2. When using dates in a GeoJSON source, you've to declare which columns (properties) are "date". In this case, it's the 'TIME' property:

```js
    const source = new carto.source.GeoJSON(geojson, { dateColumns: ['TIME'] });
```

These settings are explained in the [GeoJSON source reference](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#cartosourcegeojson)

3. You've declared an `@animation` variable in your viz, but you're not using it. This is an example to use it with the `filter` viz property, but I'd recommend you to read the [Animated Visualizations Guide](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/guides/animated-visualizations/)

```js
    const viz = new carto.Viz(`
      @animation: animation(linear($TIME, time('2019-03-20T00:00:00'), time('2019-03-24T23:00:00')), 1)
      filter: @animation
    `);
```

I'm adding here a [working example](https://bl.ocks.org/elenatorro/c35094e1941b4a188e590264114e6f30) with the code from your question.

Comment: Great! It works! Thank you very much!! The error was that i didn't declare the date Columns.